# MySQL DateTime select with interval

Tags: mysql, intervals

I am trying to select from a table where a DateTime field is older than 15 minutes.  The query seemed to be working fine till just after midnight.  Not sure how to make MySQL distinguish between AM and PM.  Any help in the right direction would be helpful.

Example:

> Current time: 11:50 (AM)
>
> last_successful_run: 12:02 (AM)
>
> This should be selected b/c 12:02 (AM) is over 15 older than 11:50 (am)
>
> Insert in the format "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"

last_successful_run is type DATETIME Default/Expression = NULL

Table

```
ID |  last_successful_run
1  |  2019-02-07 12:06:37
2  |  2019-02-07 12:05:15
3  |  2019-02-07 12:00:12
4  |  2019-02-07 12:10:37
```

SELECT QRY

```
SELECT `ID`
    FROM reports.tests 
    WHERE `last_successful_run` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)
```

Comment: Whats the datatype off the `last_successful_run` column? "

Comment: @RaymondNijland He says: _last_successful_run is type DATETIME Default/Expression = NULL_, but  I will like to say a sample of input and his expected output, what is not working fine?

Comment: @Shidersz The table sample above are DATETIME taken at midnight today (am).  and 11:50am is after 12:06am

Comment: MySQL has no problem distinguishing between am and pm

Comment: @RaymondNijland 11:59pm, 12:00am, 12:01am ..... 1:01am .. 11:50am.

Comment: @RaymondNijland  I think the issue is b/c of the insert is in the format "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"

Comment: Check your comment part "11:50am is after 12:06am" which you comment before which i qouted i mine least comment..  This makes your question confusing besides the 12 hour clock system does not make sense to me because iam used into using the 24 hour clock system..  "insert is in the format "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" " Yea like i comment before and removed the MySQL stores dates in UTC format in DATETIME/TIMESTAMP datatypes which does not know AM and PM times because it's a 24 hours clock notation..

Comment: @RaymondNijland You are correct.  I believe the issue is in the format that the data is inserted.  I think by changing the format to use HH for hours, I should solve my problem.  But i need to wait till 1am to test it.  Thanks

Comment: I don't think you need to wait. But if you're actually using AM/PM anywhere in your code I suggest you run `SELECT CAST('2019-02-07 12:00pm' AS DATETIME), CAST('2019-02-07 12:00am' AS DATETIME);` to realise you're being ignored.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Looks like changing hh -> HH solved my issue.

Comment: Not sure what you mean or what you changed.. Because `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP` datatypes storing formats can't be changed they are fixed.. Unless you are using `STR_TO_DATE(..)` or `DATE_FORMAT(..)` when selecting to convert the inserted formatting

Comment: @RaymondNijland Correct, I am using a date to string format before inserting the results into the database.  That was the root of my problems.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was on the insert to the database.  By changing the insert format of the string from "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" to "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", this allows inserts transition from 2018-02-23 02:24:24 to 2018-02-23 14:24:24.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility could be that you are checking it against your local machine time and MySQL installed on another machine with different time.

Comment: That is not the issue b/c the mysql is running on the same server

Comment: This question is totally wrong it can't never be the issue @SariRahal ... `NOW()` is a MySQL function which always give the local MySQL server time even if the MySQL client did send it from a other machine/pc.

Comment: Please share the output of this query             SELECT `ID`,last_successful_run,now() 
    FROM reports.tests 
    WHERE `last_successful_run` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)